# Cannot obtain current location error in ios while calling getCurrentPositionAsync exo sdk 34

Tags: react-native, expo

Recently I upgraded from *expo SDK 32* to version *34*. As part of these changes, I changed the references to the *expo-location* library. The *expo-location* version is `6.0.0`.

After this upgrade, the `Location.getCurrentPositionAsync` function throws the following error from iOS devices (Not simulators) intermittently:

> `Cannot obtain current location: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0(null)`

I have tried different things, however no luck.

Anyone else facing this issue?